# How do I Sum Array elements in every second

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to sum up the array of elements by every seconds. My array has 20 elements, and it should be summed up in 20seconds.

I'm using `setTimeout` in `for` loop but its not working , the loop finish before the first second. Anyway to achieve ?

```
for (var o = 0; o < 20; o++) {
   setTimeout(function () {
       tempPsum += array[o];
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to wait a second before adding each array entry?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder to display the sum of the array in HTML

Comment: ...and what notifies the HTML that `tempPsum` has changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right, the loop finishes before the first `setTimeout` callback occurs. Your code schedules 20 callbacks that all occur, one after another, a second later.

You have two choices:

1. Schedule each one a second later than the previous one, or
2. Don't schedule the next one until the previous one finishes

#1 is simpler, so let's do that:

```
for (let o = 0; o < 20; o++) {
//   ^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
   setTimeout(function () {
       tempPsum += array[o];
   }, 1000 * o);
//        ^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
}
```

By multiplying the delay time by `o`, we get `0` for the first timer, `1000` for the second, `3000` for the third...

Note the change from `var` to `let`. That way, there's a separate `o` for the callback to close over for each loop iteration. (See [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), or...Chapter 2 of my new book. :-) )

If you can't use ES2015+ features in your environment, you can use the extra arguments to `setTimeout` instead:

```
for (var o = 0; o < 20; o++) {
   setTimeout(function (index) {
//                      ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−
       tempPsum += array[index];
//                       ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−
   }, 1000 * o, o);
//        ^^^^−−^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−
}
```

That tells `setTimeout` to pass the third argument you give it to the callback as its first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Ideal use case of `setTimeout()` is when you have to perform an operation once after a specific time frame. The scenario mentioned above requires same operation that is adding array element after a fixed time frame, so I believe `setInterval()` would be a better option.

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
var tempSum = 0, i = 0;
var intrvl = setInterval( ()=> {
  tempSum += array[i++];
  console.log(tempSum)
  if(i === array.length)
    clearInterval(intrvl)
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer doesn't explain what the issue is, but offers an alternative to the other solutions. Instead of modifying the timeout using the index, you could add a `sleep` function that resolves a promise in a given amount of time.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

Then loop through your array using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and `sleep` each iteration for a given amount of time.

```
let sum = 0;
for (const number of numbers) {
  await sleep(1000);
  sum += number;
}
```

This does require the code to be placed in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).

```js
const randomInt = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const numbers = Array.from({length: 20}, () => randomInt(10, 99));
console.log("numbers =", ...numbers);

(async () => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const number of numbers) {
    await sleep(1000);
    console.log(sum, "+", number, "=", sum += number);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

@TJCrowder has said why your version doesn't work.

I will suggest another solution:

#### Another way: use setInterval

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

let tempPsum = 0

let i = 0

    let intervalId = setInterval(function () {
       tempPsum += numbers[i];
       i = i + 1;
       console.log(tempPsum);

       if (i == 20) {clearInterval(intervalId)}
   }, 1000);
```

Comment: @HemantHalwai many people will think setInterval given the same question - I did not copy your answer; in any case I have given you an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this approach:

```js
var i = 0;
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var sum = 0;
    
function myLoop() {         
  setTimeout(() => {
    sum = sum + arr[i];
    console.log(sum);
    i++;
    if (i < 20) {        
      myLoop();        
    }       
  }, 1000)
}
    
myLoop();
```